# Native crash programmatically

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik

Is there an easy way to crash an app with a native crash, in order to test native crash reporting?

note that I'm looking for a general solution for all devices, and not device specific. I thought about using the Unsafe class (writing illegal addresses into the stuck), but it looks like it's not supported

Comment: Write `*(int*)0 = 0;` in a native SO.

Comment: Can I do something from the java?

Comment: There was a question on SO to that effect. As far as I can recall, they couldn't find a good way. Exploiting known Android bugs might get you somewhere, but that's hardly device independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cause a crash from Java code, use [`dalvik.system.VMDebug.crash()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/VMDebug.java#333).  This is not part of the public API, so you will need to access it through reflection.  This worked for Dalvik; I don't know if it still works for Art.

Some of the `sun.misc.Unsafe` methods are supported, so you may be able to cause a crash by selecting an appropriate value for `offset` in calls like `putIntVolatile()`.  If the offset is the negation of the Object pointer you'll dereference address zero and crash.

The most reliable way is to create a trivial native library with the NDK.  I personally favor storing a value in a "named" address, like `0xdeadd00d`, because they let you know that it was your code crashing deliberately, but null pointer derefs work too.

Comment: This method no longer exists in modern copies of AOSP.

Answer (score 2):

As @fadden pointed out the use of [`dalvik.system.VMDebug.crash()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/VMDebug.java#333), here is a helper method to access it via reflection.

```
public void crashNatively() {
    try {
        Class.forName("dalvik.system.VMDebug")
                .getMethod("crash")
                .invoke(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method no longer exists in modern copies of AOSP.